# How can i get all browsers current tabs URL using java?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am working on a project where i need the browser URL of all tabs using JAVA or JSP. I have tried javascript code execute to java and got HELLO WORLD output but all i need is URL tabs of all browsers currently open.

I tried so far:

```
    String script = "function hello(name) { print('Hello, ' + name); }";
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval(script);
    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
    inv.invokeFunction("hello", "Scripting!!" );
```

Comment: You need native javascript provided by web browsers, what you are trying so far is ScriptEngineManager in java, which has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any standard JAVA API to do this or any standard API's provided by web browsers that will server your purpose and the ScriptEngineManager you are using doesn't help you to get the URLs.

There is an option though where you can execute certain OS commands and parse the output and you might get the URLs.

Here is an article that might help you get started: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077567/core-java/java-tip-66--control-browsers-from-your-java-application.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are **using chrome** you can make use of **AWTRobot**

Code:

```
public String getUrl(){
Thread.sleep(3000);// 
Robot r=new Robot();
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT); /* to get focus on taskbar
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);       */
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);  /* to copy it*/
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        String selectedText =(String)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); // it extracts the highlighted text of system clipboard
        return selectedText;
}
```